# SQL Replace an empty SQL SELECT with word else post the result in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, case

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I would like to make a select, when the result is empty it should be replaced with 'empty' Else all lines of the result should be there.
Like:

```
if (select has no result)
{
 One Line as result with 'no result'
}
else
{
 post every line of the select result
}
```

That is my try:

```
select case when count(*) = 0
   then 'no Entry'
   else Members --all Members should be here
END as Member
from tableMember where Membergroup = 'testgroup';
```

Thanks to everybody who can help me!

PLEASE show me the COMPLETE code that is needed to use the query in **Oracle**

Comment: If in C#, create a counter in a `while(rdr.Read())` loop. If that counter remains 0, then print one line, else print them all..

Comment: Um... you have written Oracle everywhere but none of this is Oracle code... what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

*FOR ORACLE*

```
DECLARE C INTEGER;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO C FROM tableMember WHERE Membergroup = 'testgroup';

IF C > 0
THEN
    SELECT * FROM tableMember;
ELSE
    SELECT 'No results!' FROM tableMember;
END IF;
```

*MS-SQL ONLY*

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableMember WHERE Membergroup = 'testgroup')
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tableMember
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'No results!'
END
```

Comment: Updated with your table and column names according to you attempt.

Comment: This is great, but how can i start it?
I have an sql file where i normaly make my selects on the databse.
I can not create procedures and so on. I need it as one query. Where is no ; in the statement?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how can i start it'? There are no `;` in the statement as you don't need them for MS-SQL, which is what I based this on, what RDMS are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle. As far as I know, every query needs a ; at the end. Can you give me the complete code to use it in oracle? Is it a procedure?

Comment: I have made a version that _should_ work for Oracle, but I haven't tested it! As far as I know you should be able to use it like any other select statement.

Comment: But oracle is missing a procedure?
Can you change it that I see the definition and execution of the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @counter int

SET  @counter = (select count(*) from tableMember where Membergroup = 'testgroup');

IF (@counter > 0)
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM Members
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT 'No results!'
END
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do this in the application code rather than stored procedures. What you are trying to do here is user experience related work which IMHO is something database should not care about.